# How to identify if a file is copied from a particular archive?

Tags: ant

I am new to ANT.

I have a very specific scenario to handle in this:

STEP-1: I need to look for the pattern of filenames in certain ear files. If the pattern matches then I need to extract those files.
STEP-2: And if any file is extracted from a certain ear (similar to zip-file) file, then I need to search for another set of files, and copy those set of files too.

The case to handle is "How to identify if a file is copied from a particular archive" if found then proceed to step 2, else move to next archive.

I have achieved STEP-1 but no idea how to achieve step-2.

STEP-1

```
<!-- Set via arguments passed -->
<patternset id="pattern.needtocopy" includes="${needtocopyfile.pattern}" excludes="${ignore.pattern}"> 
 </patternset>

<target name="get-binaries-from-baseline">
<for param="binary">
    <path>
        <fileset dir="${baseline.dir}/target/aaa/bbb/ccc" includes="*.ear" />
    </path>
    <sequential>
        <basename file="@{binary}" property="@{binary}.basename" />

        <unzip src="@{binary}" dest="${baseline.dir}">
            <patternset refid="pattern.needtocopy" />
            <mapper type="flatten" />
        </unzip>
    </sequential>
</for>
</target>
```

STEP-2:

????

Need help in this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I resolved the same, using a groovy script based on the resources I could find.

```
<target name="findJars">
    <zipfileset id="found" src="${ear-name}">
        <patternset refid="${patternsetref}" />
    </zipfileset>
    <groovy>
        project.references.found.each {
            println it.name
            println project.properties.'ear-name'
            println project.properties.'dest.dir'
        }
    </groovy>
</target>
```

And then I added another task which takes this filename and ear-file-name as input and extracts the related jars based on file to search pattern.